# How to keep AngularJS menu open when changing url

Tags: angularjs

I need to keep a menu open when changing url. Right now if I click on View File or Diff the menu hides because the url will have a different path (/files , /diff).

Is there any way to prevent the menu from hiding when the url is changed?

This is my code:

```
    <a href="#" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">Click to toggle menu</a>
    <div ng-show="collapsed">
        <div class=container" ng-controller="MenuController" ng-show="show_menu()" ng-init="init_file_ids(number_of_files, selected_files)">
            <a href="/#files">View File</a> |
            <a href="/#diff">Diff</a> |
            <a href="#" ng-click="set_current_view('import')">Import</a> |
            <a href="#" ng-click="toggle_chart()">Toggle chart</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please share your controller and routes code; particular interest is - show_menu function and MenuController

Answer (score 0):

you want to make sure that collapsed variable is always set false when the pages are initiated.  probably you can do that through controllers or from menu's directive controller.